# Position an image when it's parent has overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an image inside its container. Because the container has `overflow:hidden`, it is hiding half of the image — I would like to add `bottom: 50%`, so it shows the center of the image.

At the moment, if I do so, you see a gap between the image and its parent. Would anyone know how to position this, so you get to see the center of the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/RGfdh/1/

```
<div class="img-ctnr-med">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>

img {

    background-color:grey;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.img-ctnr-med {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Is the image always 200 pixels tall?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `bottom: -50%` instead, so it shifts the image 50% of the height of the container *down* towards the bottom edge of the container rather than *up* away from it.

When specifying values for [`top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props), positive values shift an element away from the respective side and negative values shift an element towards the respective side.

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
img {
  background-color:grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

To

```
img {
  background-color:grey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top:-50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to include the image as background image. It is cleaner then moving around elements. See this Fiddle as [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cAY37/1/).

html:

```
<div class="img-ctnr-med">
    <a href="#" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);">link text</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
img {

    background-color:grey;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
}

.img-ctnr-med a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: ;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```